# TypeScript Incremental Strictness

Tags: typescript

I have a fairly large Typescript project and I'd like to make it more strict. In particular, we have an issue with null-checking in a lot of places so I'd like to use the strict null-checks option. However, there are thousands of errors and its not exactly possible to fix that anytime soon.

But as I'm writing new code, I'd like to be strict with non-nullable types so I'm not piling onto the mess. Is there any way to incrementally improve the strictness of a Typescript project so all new code has strict null checks?

Comment: The simplest thing is to just ignore the current number of errors, and simply ensure they do not increase. TypeScript errors should not prevent emit. If you're doing some kind of CI, you can take the TypeScript error log and do some kind of sedding to eliminate "approved" errors.

Comment: I think that the best approach here would be to use two different `tsconfig.json` files, one which is strict for the new code and another for the old code. If you can separate the source code into different libraries it will be best (the output dir can be the same), otherwise, you can probably pull that off by combination of `files`, `include` and `exclude`.

Comment: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2018/06/20/how-to-actually-improve-type-safety-with-the-typescript-strict-flags "It took approximately 400 engineer-hours to enable just the noImplicitAny flag by hand for our codebase. This process was spread over 150 days from start to finish" so apparently... only doable by splitting a project into sub libs but if you've got a huge project, this might take a looooong time.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [typescript-strict-plugin](https://github.com/allegro/typescript-strict-plugin) which allows you to turn on strict mode in specific files or directories.

#### 1. Install the package

```
npm i -D typescript-strict-plugin
```

#### 2. Add the plugin to your tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...
    "strict": false,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-strict-plugin",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### 3. Mark files you want to strictify with @ts-strict comment

Before:

```
//no strict comment here
...
const name: string = null; // no error here
```

After:

```
//@ts-strict
...
const name: string = null; // TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the optimal solution is to extend the tsconfig.json with a new one which enables strictNullChecks and which will be used in the IDE.

1. When creating a new functionality there will be strictNullChecks errors in the IDE, it's OK.
2. When refactoring existing code, the appeared strictNullChecks errors will cause you to fix the code. Thus, there will be a gradual migration of the source code to fully enable the strictNullChecks.

Answer (score 0):

Build two TS config files:

- `tsconfig.json`:

  - non-strict TS checks
  - the `include` entry contains all the paths or globs in your old source code base. With a few lines of code it should be fairly easy to get it
- `tsconfig-strict.json`:

  - strict TS checks
  - the `include` entry contains your whole codebase
  - extends `tsconfig.json` so as to avoid duplication

Use the first one for development, and the second one to build your code for production or programmatically check for strict error (eg `tsc --project tsconfig-strict.json`).